# how get indexed value from PHP object output of simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

From the output1 below we can see that PHP `simplexml_load_file` translates the same `index` tags as indexed array `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

I would like to find out how can I get the index from the output of `simplexml_load_file`? I tired to do that with example 'php2', and I got 'output2' in return. Is it possible or how can I get my output as shown on 'desired output2'? Thank you in advance

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report>
    <index><value>h</value></index>
    <index><value>e</value></index>
    <index><value>l</value></index>
    <index><value>l</value></index>
    <index><value>o</value></index>
</Report>
```

php1:

```
<?php
    $oFile = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("error: Cannot create object");
    var_dump($oFile);
?>
```

output1:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) 
{ 
    ["index"]=> array(5) 
    { 
        [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { ["value"]=> string(1) "h" } 
        [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) { ["value"]=> string(1) "e" } 
        [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) { ["value"]=> string(1) "l" } 
        [3]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["value"]=> string(1) "l" } 
        [4]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) { ["value"]=> string(1) "o" } 
    } 
}
```

php2:

```
<?php
    $oFile = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("error: Cannot create object");
    foreach ($oFile->index as $key=>$value) {
        echo $key.': '.$value->value.'<br>';
    }
?>
```

output2:

```
index: h
index: e
index: l
index: l
index: o
```

desired output2:

```
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple XML is painful to work with:

```
$oFile = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

foreach($oFile->xpath("index") as $key => $value) {
        echo "{$key}: {$value->value}<br>";
}
```

Comment: This solution works! If anyone has a more elegant or different solutions to this question, please post. I'll vote for the best answer in a few days. Thank you so much!

Comment: *Simple XML is painful to work with*?! I can see by the number of lines of code it has taken that it is really complex :-/

Comment: @NigelRen The reason it's so painful is because you're not given access to a PHP object. It looks like a PHP `SimpleXMLElement` object, but it is in fact a libxml resource that automatically converts to a string when you print it. That's why it prints as if it is an array, but it's not an actual array.

Comment: I realized to access 'e' directly without foreach: '$oFile->index[1]->value'

Comment: `index[1]` - that almost looks as though you are accessing it as though it was an array.  This is done as SimpleXMLElement allows access to the underlying data in a  more intuitive way, no need to use XPath as in the answer.

Comment: 'xpath' is needed, I am working with a much more complex 'XML' file, I just have to narrow it down as much as possible to solve the problem, on this post. I have to use the 'xpath' to access the 'array' index. To access the content, I tried something similar like '$oFile->index->1->value' and it wouldn't work. That's why I post what I found, in case someone else encountered the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use a counter to have the key...

```
$key = 0;
foreach ( $oFile->index as $index ) {
    echo ($key++)."=>".$index->value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or if you are going to process the data further, you can just add it to an array...

```
$data = [];
foreach ( $oFile->index as $index ) {
    $data[] = (string)$index->value;
}
print_r($data);
```

which gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => h
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
    [4] => o
)
```

Comment: or: `$data = $oFile->xpath('*/value')`.

Answer (score 1):

As you were asking for a more elegant way and you said you need xpath, this is basically the same as the accepted answer but w/o the complaints and using it for the benefit:

```
foreach ($oFile->xpath('*/value') as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ': ', $value, "\n";
}
```

If you use xpath anyway, it does already turn the result into an array of SimpleXMLElements - zero indexed.

Additionally directly querying the nodes you are interested in brings the benefit to actually turn their text-content into a string by echoing (which casts it as string):

```
0: h
1: e
2: l
3: l
4: o
```

Hope this adds a bit of benefit to the answers so far.

- [Demo](https://3v4l.org/gi1S2)